# Does vegan cheese ever melt?

Tags: vegan

I have a kind of vegan friend and recently made a pizza for her. I went to a vegan shop, bought "vegan mozzarella" (they said it melts ok), and cooked the pizza as usual. Does vegan cheese ever melt? Is it the limit of how much it can melt? Or did I buy a bad sort of vegan cheese?

[image]

Comment: i’ve had a vegan cheese that melted, but I don’t know that all do

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it melts, at least the stuff my friend who can no longer eat cheese uses does. *They have a "more complex milk issue than mere lactose-intolerance" before the unsolicited commentary about lactose free cheese rolls in...would that it were that simple.*

But it takes considerably longer to melt than real mozzarella. So "cooked as usual" my experience is that the real cheese pizza is done while the vegan cheese pizza is still considering the possibility that it might melt.

Comment: It got singed. The only possibility it was considering by the time I took it out of the oven was to get singed even more

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev some specialty (usually high price) vegan cheeses can melt like real cheese, the vast majority at this point do not.